# How to cut out specific pieces of a string

Tags: java, substring

So I have a string that has several start markers and end markers. How can I make a code that only keeps segments that are between the start and end markers?

A good example would be DNA transcription.

So the starting marker would be TAC, and an end marker would be ACT.
I have a string: AGA**TACACGACT**AGCGAGC**TACGATACT**ACC.

I know how to use the substring method, but not well enough so that it cuts the string down to:
TACACGACTTACGATACT.

How can I do this?

EDIT: I have solved this problem by writing this method:

```
private String spliceString(String n){
    int counter1 = 0;
    int startloc = 0;
    int endloc = 0;
    String m = "";
    while (n.indexOf("TAC",counter1) != -1){
        startloc = n.indexOf("TAC",counter1);
        if (n.indexOf("ACT", counter1) != -1){
            endloc = n.indexOf("ACT", counter1);
        }
        else if (n.indexOf("ATT", counter1) != -1){
            endloc = n.indexOf("ATT", counter1);
        }
        else if (n.indexOf("ATC", counter1) != -1){
            endloc = n.indexOf("ATC", counter1);
        }
        else {
            return "AAAA"; //Returns a error string. This will be caught in another method that is not relevant.
        }
        m = m + n.substring(startloc,endloc + 3);
        counter1 = endloc + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(m); //Just prints out so to check if the code worked
    return m;
}
```

Comment: What code have you written to try this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service

Comment: Add a sample code of yours please, so that every developer could help you on behalf of your code.

Comment: there are many solutions search on google then try if you get any problem then ask here

Comment: Sorry about not putting my code inititally. My original code was extremely flawed and would not have helped to find the solution. I have posted what I found to work instead

Answer (score 0):

For this, regular expression is your friend.

One way would be to search for what you want to keep, and collect that in a `StringBuilder`.

```
String input = "AGATACACGACTAGCGAGCTACGATACTACC";
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("TAC.*?ACT").matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    buf.append(m.group());
String output = buf.toString();
System.out.println(output); // prints: TACACGACTTACGATACT
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/s3LKbV) for running code.

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) of `Pattern` for more information on regex.

---

Alternatively, delete what you don't want to keep, i.e.

- Text before first `TAC`
- Text between `ACT` and `TAC`
- Text after last `ACT`

The code is much simpler, but the regex is a bit more complex:

```
String input = "AGATACACGACTAGCGAGCTACGATACTACC";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=^|ACT).*?(?=TAC|$)", "");
System.out.println(output); // prints: TACACGACTTACGATACT
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rY7mZ2/1) for nice color-coded example.

Answer (score 0):

**Java - String substring() Method**

**Description:**

This method has two variants and returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string or up to endIndex - 1 If second argument is given.

**Syntax:**

Here is the syntax of this method:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
```

or

public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)

**Parameters:**

Here is the detail of parameters:

beginIndex  --  the begin index, inclusive.

endIndex  --  the end index, exclusive.

**Return Value:**
The specified substring.

**Example:**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.substring(10) );

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.substring(10, 15) );
   }
}
```

This produces the following result:

```
Return Value : Tutorialspoint.com
Return Value : Tuto
```